# What is a .apple extension?

Tags: macos, uti

What is a .apple extension? I am recovering some files and I recovered several files with the .apple extension.

Comment: (1) Are the filenames familiar? How about full name examples? (2) I added the file-extension tag, and removed the mac tag due to being implicitly obvious. (3) Which version of OS X are we talking about?

Comment: Interesting.  filext.com only finds that extension for an Apple II file.

Comment: @VxJasonV Thanks for the tag change. The file names are as follows: f0009024.apple, f0009088.apple, & f0012416.apple. So to answer your question, no they aren't familiar. I am on OS 10.6.8

Comment: I opened the .apple files in TextEdit: Here's the first file: f0009024.apple:

Comment: Mac OS X         2∞‚@ATTR;ö…ˇ‚xThis resource fork intentionally left blank   ˇˇ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the terminal command `file f0009024.apple` show you about the files have.

It's highly unlikely they are truncated [Apple Single or Apple Double files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats), but that's the only guess I have at the moment.

Comment: It says: AppleDouble encoded Macintosh file. What is that?

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! - see the wikipedia article linked above. The free stuffit on the app store should unpack it for you (assuming it's not corrupt or the orphaned second half of the main file) Also RFC1740 (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1740.txt) should put you to sleep reading about this format.

Comment: I opened them with Stuffit Expander, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

To decode AppleDouble, try this AppleScript

```
on run   
    tell application "Decode AppleFile"
        activate
        set outputFile to decode file "Macintosh HD:Desktop Folder:encoded:SomeFile.hqx"
        -- set outputFile to decode file "Macintosh HD:encoded:%aFile" data fork file "Macintosh HD:encoded:aFile"   end tell   tell application "Finder"
        activate
        select outputFile
        move selection to folder "Macintosh HD:decoded"   
    end tell 
end run
```